# Theme.Dialog не закрывать активити при нажатии вне него

Tags: android, java

Нужно не закрывать активити при нажатии вне него. (При [@android](/users/8445/android):style/Theme.Dialog конечно)

Comment: можно более развернутый вопрос? Если что-то не нравиться в базовом функционале - наследуся и переопределяй методы

Comment: Вроде всё ясно, при нажатии вне диалога он закрывается, нужно это исключить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вызовите у диалога метод

```
setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```